# Qs about interpretations on Parmenides's claim

Tags: logic, ontology

Parmenides's classic claim is that **what does not exist cannot be thought about**. (It has been read as a claim that every truth-bearer must have a truth-maker, since otherwise the truth-bearer is not about anything.)

Can I understand this sentence as the following: **what is thought about is what exists (e.g., reality)**?

And, if I reverse its order like: **what cannot be thought about does not exist,**
does this sentence now have the same meaning or emphasis as Parmenides's?

Answer (score 3):

I think one can read Parmenides's claim as saying that intentional properties (being thought about etc.) are existence entailing. So your first construal of that claim is quite right. But notice that Parmenides's has some modal flavour, which is also implicit in the usual understanding of property entailment. So you should prefix your first construal with some operator of (metaphysical) necessity.

Your second construal is not equivalent to your first. For otherwise 'Necessarily for all x, if x is human, then x is an animal' and 'Necessarily for all x, if x is not human, then x is not an animal' would be equivalent. But obviously they are not, since the first claim is true and the second is false. You're simply misapplying the usual rules of contraposition for material (or, for that matter, strict) implication.

Comment: Great help! Learn a lot from your answers. Really thank you.